# Link deep into Mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose, schema

I want to link Person to a subdivision within Divisions.

```
Divisions = new Schema({
  division_name: String
  subdivisions: [{
     subdivisions_name: String 
  }]
})

People = new Schema({
  name: String,
  subdivision: *???*
})
```

Looking at the stored documents, subdivisions have an `_id`, so I would think this would be a possible thing.

To be clear, I have many documents with many different depths, and many may link to any given one, so it's not quite as simple as the schemas above, but if someone can demonstrate this I can adapt it for my model.

Doing so without splitting Divisions into multiple schemas would be much preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be achieved with populate.

```
var subdivisionSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var divisionSchema = new Schema({
  division_name: String
  subdivisions: [subdivisionSchema]
});
var peopleSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  subdivision: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Divisions'},
});

// Connect to DB and instantiate models    
var db = mongoose.connect('enter your database here');
var People = db.model('People', peopleSchema);
var Division  = db.model('Division', divisionSchema);
var Subdivision = db.model('Subdivision', subdivisionSchema);

// Find and populate
People.find({}).populate('subdivisions.name').exec(function(err, items) {
    console.log(peoples[0].divisions[0].subdivisions.name);
});
```

Comment: So then, if I have 100 people with that subdivision, how do I get those 100 people? I guess I'm confused as to how it knows to link the "subdivision" property to the "subdivision" collection _id.

Comment: Take a look at the original documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html scroll down to query conditions and other options